# Linked-Lists Bubble Sort

Tags: c, list, sorting

I am wondering how to implement a bubble sort on a singly-linked list. Let's say for example that we have list that consists of following nodes:

```
struct node {
   int value;
   struct node* next;
}
```

I believe that there are 2 ways to acomplish this:

```
1)to directly exchange `values` in memory
2)to change `nexts`, to point to a different nodes
```

Which way is more efficient, and can somebody give me some example on how to do it? I'm aware that using Bubble Sort isn't very efficient compared to other sorting algorithms.

Comment: As long as you don't give a hoot about perf: just create an array from the list, sort, re-create the list from the sorted array.

Comment: I would like to see *memory locality* issues addressed in relationship to the algorithm -- assume a relatively large `n`. In the above example the value is an int and thus (presumably) no larger than the pointer in size, so let's assume the #1 and #2 "the same" in terms of processor instructions.

Comment: I can't think of a good reason to implement bubble sort on linked lists. The algorithm itself on arrays is already *fracking* slow, why punish yourself harder using linked-lists?

Comment: @pst: "the same", except that to switch the values in two nodes requires swapping two integers. To switch the positions of two adjacent nodes in a singly-linked lists requires cycling 3 stored "next" pointers (in the predecessor of the first one, and the two being moved). Still the same kind of thing, though, and irrelevant by comparison to the choice of algorithm.

Comment: @SteveJessop I'm not sure it's irrelevant by choice of algorithm. Depending upon all those "soft factors" like caching and cache lines, it may be significantly faster to iterate through the linked list if it is increasingly "in order" w.r.t where it is allocated (I made the assumption that the linked cells were allocated as a single block or somehow otherwise continuous in memory, which may not hold.)

Comment: @pst: sure, I meant more or less what you said in the first comment, that the choice between 1 and 2 is irrelevant by comparison to the choice of algorithm. Caching might be relevant, but I doubt that the difference between a swap and a 3-cycle is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your values are very small, so I expect exchanging them to be more efficient than changing the pointer structure. As always, you will have to measure the actual performance in your use case to be sure.

Comment: But what if i would have several values inside a structure?

Comment: @Melvin For some value size, exchanging the values becomes less efficient the changing the pointer structure. The exact point depends on your platform and use case.

Answer (score 2):

You have to consider various special cases if you exchange the `nexts`. This makes it a little bit slower than changing `value`s. If your values have more structure you have either the option to implement the `next`-version or replace value by a pointer.